# If Statement in Python (Nested Boolean statements)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

I have no Idea if the title uses the correct terms but I am looking to get some code and to try and reduce the length of the code so It will be quicker for me to type in the assessment. Here is and Example of How it would look if I did it the long winded way.

```
Valid = True
while Valid:
  Column = int(input("Insert Column: "))
  Row = int(input("Insert Row: "))
  if Row < 0 or Row > 9 or Column < 0 or Column > 9:
    Valid = False
```

However, I was trying to to make that smaller by doing something along the lines of:

```
"If (Row or Column) < 0 or (Row or Column) > 0:
   valid = False"
```

Can someone explain why it doesn't seem work and can someone please demonstrate how they would solve it. I am only trying to slim down my if statements since throughout the assessment I will be using a large amount of them.

*Update:- Can this also be put into a Try - Catch so it wouldn't crash the program upon entering a Null Value or No value*

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the if statement completely.

```
Valid = True
while Valid:
  try:
     Column = int(input("Insert Column: "))
     Row = int(input("Insert Row: "))
     Valid = Row in range(10)  and Column in range(10)
  except Exception as e:
     print(e)
     Valid = False
```

Comment: While this works, I'd advise using a chained comparison `0 <= row < 10` instead of `row in range(10)`, since it behaves better on Python 2 or if you try to use the same construct with floats.

Comment: Switching the sense of the test and unconditionally setting `Valid` is a good move.

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to a true value for valid again?

Comment: In your example, you set valid to false when it's outside the range. In my code, I set it true when it's inside the range and false when it's outside the range. So it leads to the same answer. My way just has a little less code.

Comment: How would you adapt it for a Try - Catch Scenario

Comment: You might want to catch a specific `ValueError` rather than `Exception`.

Answer (score 3):

The `or` operator is a short-circuiting comparison that returns the earliest truthy value, or the last value if none are truthy. In `(Row or Column) < 0`, first `Row or Column` is evaluated. If `Row` is nonzero, that section returns `Row`. Otherwise, it would return `Column`. It then compares this single value to `0`. The same goes for the other comparison, which I assume has a typo and was intended to be `(Row or Column) > 9` (rather than `> 0`).

You can also try the following (not an exhaustive list):

```
if not 0<=row<=9 or not 0<=column<=9
if row not in range(10) or column not in range(10)
if not all(0<=x<=9 for x in (row,column))
```

Choose the one that makes the most sense in the context of your program.

Comment: @Bahrom - ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How would you then adapt this for a Try - Catch Statement

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but this create an array of 10 elements [0..9]..

```
Valid = True
rangeValue = range(10)
while Valid:
  Column = int(input("Insert Column: "))
  Row = int(input("Insert Row: "))
  Valid = Row in rangeValue and Column in rangeValue
```

Comment: `range()` is not inclusive at both ends.